Reorder lines in stat_cor and stat_regline_equation to match legend
I'm using stat_cor and stat_regline_equation from ggpubr to plot coefficients and equations on a ggplot in R. I've reordered the variables in the legend using scale_color_continuous, but it appears stat_cor and stat_regline_equation don't respond to the function. How would I match the coefficients and equations order to the legend order?
Code:
ggplot(summeravgs30, aes(AvgNightLST, NightTmp, color = Region)) +
     geom_point(size = 4, shape = 17) +
     geom_smooth(method = lm) +
     labs(x = "Mean Night LST (°C)", y = "Average Night SAT (°C)") +
     scale_x_continuous(limits = c(22,28)) + 
     scale_y_continuous(limits = c(20,36)) +
     scale_color_discrete(breaks = c("NF", "CF", "SF")) +
     stat_cor(aes(color = Region), size = 4, p.accuracy = 0.1, label.x.npc = "left", label.y = c(34.5,33.5,32.)) +
     theme_bw(base_size = 15) +
     theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 15), 
     axis.title.y = element_text(size = 15)) +
     stat_regline_equation(size = 4, label.x = c(25, 25, 25), label.y = c(22.5,21.5,20.5)) + 
     theme(legend.position = "bottom")

to get:


Try reordering the Region levels before calling ggplot. It would help if you also provided some sample data (see [MRE]).

As already pointed out by @Edward in the comments you have to convert the variable mapped on color to a factor with the levels set according to your desired order.
Using a minimal reprex based on mtcars:
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

# Example data
summeravgs30 <- mtcars[c("cyl", "hp", "mpg")]
names(summeravgs30) <- c("Region", "AvgNightLST", "NightTmp")
summeravgs30$Region <- as.character(
  factor(
    summeravgs30$Region,
    labels = c("NF", "CF", "SF")
  )
)

# Convert to a factor
summeravgs30$Region <- factor(summeravgs30$Region, c("NF", "CF", "SF"))

ggplot(summeravgs30, aes(AvgNightLST, NightTmp, color = Region)) +
  geom_point(size = 4, shape = 17) +
  geom_smooth(method = lm) +
  labs(x = "Mean Night LST (°C)", y = "Average Night SAT (°C)") +
  #scale_x_continuous(limits = c(22, 28)) +
  #scale_y_continuous(limits = c(20, 36)) +
  stat_cor(aes(color = Region),
    size = 4, p.accuracy = 0.1, label.x.npc = "left",
    label.y = c(34.5, 33.5, 32.)
  ) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 15) +
  theme(
    axis.title.x = element_text(size = 15),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size = 15)
  ) +
  stat_regline_equation(
    size = 4, label.x = c(25, 25, 25),
    label.y = c(22.5, 21.5, 20.5)
  ) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula = 'y ~ x'


